# what is this error: com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My application is ready, I had difficulties in the creation variable. when compiling the application in the release version to publish on google, the error, and not accessing my data in firebase:

what is this error: com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot

I don't know what this mistake is, I did some research but I didn't find anything, I need help. my app does not open firebase data in the release version, but in the debug version it works normally.

Comment: post your model class and data storing code